# Top-Margin Not working Instead Height is increased

Tags: html, css

I am trying to give `top-margin` to div with  `id=footer`.but it is not working instead height get increased of outer div.
HTML File:

```
<div id="lowestContainer">
    <div class="middle" id="footer">
        <address id="addressSFCM">
            xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx<br/>
            xx--xx--xx--xx<br/>
            xxx---xxx-x--x-xx-xx<br/>
            Email:xxxxx@hotmail.com
        </address>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css file:

```
#lowestContainer{
    background-color: rgba(18,19,20,1);
    height: 300px;
    z-index: 1000;
    box-shadow: 1px 0px 3px rgb(0,0,0,0.3);
}
#footer{
    width:1000px;
    height:100px;
    display:block;
}
#addressSFCM{
    color: rgba(76,76,76,1);
    max-width: 220px;
    height:auto;
    /*margin-top: 30px;*/
    display:inline;
}
```

Please help me over this problem;

Answer (score 0):

Update your footer class like below.

```
#footer{
width:1000px;
height:100px;
display:inline-block;
margin-top:100px;
text-align:center;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5CaWt/1/)

Comment: after doing this the footer doesn't remains at center

Comment: center?? didn't understand which one you are talking.

Comment: class=middle property contains `margin-left:auto;margin-right:` property.

Comment: updated my answer. use `text-align:center`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to add padding-top to the lowestContainer which yields the same result

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tVgs9/)

```
#lowestContainer{
    padding-top:30px;
}
```

Comment: ok but i need a reason why it is not working

Comment: To my understanding, Margin does not effect the child's position in relation to it's parents, unless the parent has padding (my solution demonstrates this) Read more on the box model here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html (See 8.3.1)

Comment: but sometimes it works for elements that are floated left or right

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: hidden` to wrapper

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/Fsd5N/)**

```
#lowestContainer{
  overflow: hidden;
}
#footer{
    margin-top: 50px; // add top margin as per needed
}
```

Comment: thnxx it works!! but why can you please explain the reason

Comment: When you trying to apply `top` `margin` to inner `div`, it actually working like applying top margin to parent `div` that is `#lowestContainer`. That's why when you going to apply margin to inner `div`, main wrapper `div` is shifted down.

Comment: then how `overflow:hidden` is helping here

Comment: and i have also seen that it sometimes works normally for child divs why it is so

Comment: Though we know that after applying `overflow: hidden`, the content is `clipped`. So it allows here to apply `top margin` to inner `div`. After applying `overflow:hidden', the `top margin` is applied to `inner div' and the main wrapper is `clippped`.